# Java 8 - Cannot invoke stream() on the array type Enum[]

Tags: java, enums, java-8

Why I cannot invoke `stream()` on the array type `Enum`?

```
DummyEnum[] array = DummyEnum.values();
array.stream(); // Compile Error
```

**ENUM:**

```
public enum DummyEnum {
    Hello("Hello"), Welcome("Welcome");
    private String greeting;

    private DummyEnum(final String greeting) {
        this.greeting = greeting;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

Comment: note that `DummyEnum.values()` creates a new array on each call. That's usually not a problem, but if you're doing it in extremely hot code you might want to cache a single instance in a static field instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `Stream.of(array)`. Arrays don't have a `stream()` method.

Comment: Or `EnumSet.allOf(DummyEnum.class).stream()`…